# How to send email from a HTML contact-us form

Tags: html

I'm new to Yahoo small business web hosting. I created a HTML contact-us form as shown below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Untitled Form</a></h1>
        <form id="form_774248" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Untitled Form</h2>
            <p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_1_1" name= "element_1_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_1_2" name= "element_1_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
            <label>Last</label>
        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Phone </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_2_1" name="element_2_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="element_2_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_2_2" name="element_2_2" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="element_2_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_2_3" name="element_2_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_2_3">####</label>
        </span>

        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Address </label>

        <div>
            <input id="element_3_1" name="element_3_1" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_3_1">Street Address</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="element_3_2" name="element_3_2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_3_2">Address Line 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_3_3" name="element_3_3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_3_3">City</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <input id="element_3_4" name="element_3_4" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_3_4">State / Province / Region</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_3_5" name="element_3_5" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_3_5">Postal / Zip Code</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <select class="element select medium" id="element_3_6" name="element_3_6"> 
        <label for="element_3_6">Country</label>
    </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="774248" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
            Generated by <a href="http://www.phpform.org">pForm</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried `<form action="MAILTO:test@test.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">`, but nothing worked.
Now, I want to send an email to `test@test.com` which contains all the details of the fields in the website. Should I use PHP or can I do it directly. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

### This requires a script to act as a handler and sender of the email.

Like this one: http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php

HTML/JavaScript cannot send out email directly.

The `mail()` delivery method and the `SMTP` protocol still need a **handler** such as FormMail, above. The handler will use SMTP through `mail()` usually, in PHP.

That handler would be your form `action=` and depending on the handler you use, you will need to use specific input field names to have everything sent properly.

Comment: but in w3schools...they have mentioned about MAILTO

Comment: That uses the email client on the computer being used. It does not actually send email itself. It starts up an email that *might* be sent, and provides a subject usually. This could be done with `<a href="mailto:address@domain?subject=subject">email me</a>`. If there is no email client on the computer, no email can be sent. You need to use a server-side handler to submit to.

Comment: BUT... if you change your existing way to use `method='get'`, it may work, but not in all cases. If it did work, it would be unreliable. Very unreliable. Use a form handler. You'll never regret it.